# Good way to test Electrumx?

Tags: electrum, server, testing

Has anyone else gotten an electrumx server up and running lately?

I have just gotten to the point where I'm not seeing any errors during "# service electrumx status", but I'm also not seeing my server listed in my Electrum client.

Can you think of a good way to test whether the server is working?

I would especially hate it if it did appear but still didn't work!  I don't want anyone to lose money because of me.

Answer (score 1):

A good way to test if the server works is to send a small test transaction to yourself.  You will need to tell your client about the server.  For example try using `electrum -1 -s localhost:50002`.  The `-1` makes it so you only connect to one server.